How to make a component in module of laravel
I have checked the Laravel documentation, but it only provides information on creating components in the main directory, not within a module.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/blade#components
php artisan make:component Alert

Also, I have tried this command. this is also not working.
php artisan module:make-component map Area

getting this error
getting this error
please share the right command.

i assume you plan on using the Laravel nwidart module package as Laravel does not support this out of the box.  if you already have the package installed,  you need to remove and reinstall with composer as it seems it is not installed.  i checked the available command under the package and I can see    module:make-component  is available.

Auto-discovery of components is only within the app/View/Components directory and resources/views/components directory.
These are the "main director[ies]" only.
However, as the yours in question URL following section Manually Registering Package Components continues, "if you are building a package that utilizes Blade components or placing components in non-conventional directories, you will need to manually register your component class and its HTML tag alias so that Laravel knows where to find the component." (ebd.)
It shows an example as well with a boot method of a package service provider:
...
/**
 * Bootstrap your package's services.
 */
public function boot(): void
{
    Blade::component('package-alert', AlertComponent::class);
}
...

<x-package-alert/>

(example shortened from ebd.)
Also watch out for the alternative methods outlined thereafter and the important note at the very top of the section.
Finally, double-check any skill issues reading the Laravel documentation: It is pretty slick, and when reading too fast, it's easy to skip some details required for understanding. As an older reader, it helps me to re-read it again and then often things are much more clear. YMMV.
